# Covid-19 - Spain - A completely unvaccinated person, wants the covid-certificate, logic of requiring all 3 jabs, instead of just latest 1 or 2 jabs?

Tags: covid-19

Covid-19 - Spain - A completely unvaccinated person, wants to get the covid-certificate / covid-passport, what's the logic of requiring all 3 jabs, instead of just the latest 1 or 2 jabs ?

- Is the original strain of covid that swept europe / america in early 2020, still floating around, is this the logic of requiring the first jab for a completely unvaccinated person, to be the original first jab  ?
- Why can't the 'jab' requirements for the first 'jab' for a completely unvaccinated person be quickly revised, especially in the light of the arrival of something like Omicron ?
- Just how unwise would it be to now abandon the first 1 or 2 'jabs' given here in Spain ?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is founded on a misconception. The material in the syringe is the same for all 3. It has not been adjusted for new strains. (See for example [this government of Canada info page](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/drugs-health-products/covid19-industry/drugs-vaccines-treatments/vaccines/pfizer-biontech.html) on the Pfizer vaccines.) It doesn't need to be: it protects against the new strains as well as the old. In some cases the degree of protection is slightly less, eg 92% instead of 95% kind of thing. The vaccine is the vaccine and that's that.

Like many other vaccinations, full immunity requires more than one dose. (See [this example](https://www.hepb.org/prevention-and-diagnosis/vaccination/guidelines-2/) for hepatitis.) You can't get "just the third jab." Whatever you get now will be your first. You will have some protection, and several weeks later you can have a second and get more.

The exact spacing between vaccinations varies with factors like "how much vaccine do we have?" - some countries delayed second shots to get more people first shots, then it turned out those people had more immunity so the recommendations changed to a longer spacing. But now we're facing things like "against Omicron it's better to have a second that gives you x% (even though you'd get x+something% if you waited) than just a first that gives you a much smaller y% protection."

Anyway, go get one shot. It will give you some protection. Then, after the spacing recommended where you live - probably 3 to 8 weeks - get a second. Then don't worry about the third for 6 months after that.

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds. I would add something about the vaccine still protecting against these new strains too.

Comment: @bob1 good idea, done